Expressing the spin-1/2 operators in terms of the quantum rotor variables
In this paper, a spin-1/2 Hamiltonian is introduced on a cubic lattice [Eq. (12)]:
$$
H_c = -J \sum_{\Box} (S_1^+ S_2^-S_3^+S_4^- + \text{H.c.}),
$$
where the sum runs over all plaquettes of the cubic lattice and the spins are on the links of the perimeter of each plaquette. To map the model to a $U(1)$ lattice gauge theory, the authors introduced the quantum rotor variables $n_{r r^\prime} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi_{r r^\prime} \in [-\pi, \pi)$ defined on the links, with the commutation relation
$$
[\phi_{\langle r_1 r_2 \rangle}, n_{\langle r_3 r_4 \rangle}] = i \delta_{\langle r_1 r_2 \rangle, \langle r_3 r_4 \rangle}.
$$
Using the relations
$$
S^z = n-\frac{1}{2}, S^{\pm} = e^{\pm i \phi},
$$
it was stated that the model is mapped to
$$
H_c=\frac U2\sum_{\langle\mathbf{rr}^{\prime}\rangle}(n_{\mathbf{rr}^{\prime}}-1/2)^2-K\sum_{\square}\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2+\phi_3-\phi_4),
$$
where the exact mapping is achieved in the limit $U/K \to \infty$, which constrains $n = 0, 1$.
My question is about the relations between the spin operators and the rotor variables. One can show that the algebra
$$
[S^z, S^{\pm}] = \pm S^{\pm}
$$
is indeed satisfied, as
$$
[n-1/2, e^{\pm i \phi}] = \pm e^{\pm i\phi}.
$$
However, the commutator
$$
[S^+, S^-] =  2S_z
$$
is not faithfully represented,
as
$$
[S^+, S^-] = [e^{i \phi}, e^{-i \phi}] = 0.
$$
Then why can one use the relation to get the new Hamiltonian?

Is there a typo in the commutator formula? As written, it makes little sense.

Thanks for pointing that out! Now the commutation relation should be correct.

I meant the very first commutation relation.

You are right. Now it's fixed.

It is not meant to be an exact mapping. A rotor has an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, while a spin-1/2 has dimension 2. What the authors did, I think, is to use the $(n-1/2)^2$ term to energetically "truncate" the rotor Hilbert space to just two states $n=0$ and $n=1$, in the large $U$ limit. Then   you have just a two-level system, which is equivalent to a spin-1/2.

Meng's answer makes perfect sense to me. Just to make it more explicit, the $U(n-1/2)^2$ term softens the hard-core boson constraint. In the hard-core limit $U\to\infty$, the mapping is actually
$$
S^{\pm} = P e^{\pm i \phi}P, S^z = P (n-1/2) P,
$$
where $P=P_{n=0}+P_{n=1}$ projects the Hilbert space onto the subspace with particle number $n=0$ or $1$.
Then the commutations
$$
[S^z,S^+] = [P n P,P e^{i\phi}P] = P_{n=1}e^{i\phi}P_{n=0}=Pe^{i\phi}P,\\
[S^+,S^-] =[Pe^{i\phi}P, Pe^{-i\phi}P] = P_{n=1}-P_{n=0} = P(2n-1)P = 2S^z,
$$
are indeed satisfied in the subspace.
